# Exception causing close of session 0x0: null - Java + Kafka + Zookeeper + Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to use the [KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) object and I followed [this guide](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer/index.html) to achieve this. Below is the code being used:

```
private final KafkaProducer producer;
private final Serializer serializer;

public KafkaEventPublisher(String zookeeper, Serializer serializer) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, zookeeper);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaProducerTest");

    this.producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    this.serializer = serializer;
}

@Override
public <T extends Event> void publish(String streamName, T event) {
    try {
        String eventEnvelopeJson = serializer.serialize(event);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(streamName, event.getId().toString(), eventEnvelopeJson);
        this.producer.send(record);
    } finally {
        this.producer.flush();
        this.producer.close();
    }
}
```

The zookeeper string provided has the value of `localhost:2181`. Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"

  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka-manager:
    image: sheepkiller/kafka-manager
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOSTS=zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper
```

When I try to run a test case and test the above code, my docker-compose view gets spammed with this error message and eventually the testcase times out.

```
keeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:34,828 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37638
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:34,829 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:34,829 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37638 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:35,689 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37640
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:35,692 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:35,693 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37640 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:36,772 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37642
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:36,773 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:36,773 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37642 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:37,772 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37644
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:37,773 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:37,773 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37644 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:38,877 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37646
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:38,880 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:38,880 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37646 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:40,061 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37648
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:40,062 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:40,062 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37648 (no session established for client)
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:41,017 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.1:37650
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:41,019 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
zookeeper_1      | 2018-03-28 09:05:41,019 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.1:37650 (no session established for client)
```

I have not been able to find any answers online regarding this error. I hope someone can help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from this bad configuration:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, zookeeper);
```

`BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` refers to brokers, not zookeeper.

You can obtain the `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` from zookeeper using the following :

```
val zkUtils = ZkUtils(zookeeper, 3000, 3000, JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled)
val brokers = zkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster()
 .map(_.getBrokerEndPoint(ListenerName.forSecurityProtocol(SecurityProtocol.PLAINTEXT)).connectionString())
 .mkString(",")
...
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check value of 'bootstrap.servers' in the file kafka*\config\ consumer.properties and producer.properties.

The same should be the value of the port of producer and consumer. By default its generally 9092